# Convert bytes in a C array as longs

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I have a byte array in little endian byte order. How do I convert it to a long (four bytes) array?

In layman's terms, I want to merge every four bytes.

Comment: Unsafe method is `int x = *((int*) &bytearr)`. Just to show how messed up it is.

Comment: The applicable techniques might/will depend on the byte-order the resultant long as well. You said that the input is in little-endian. But what about output?

Comment: @AndreyT The outbut follows the same little endian byte-order

Comment: @frazras: In this case, depending on your performance requirements, you might carefully consider the straightforward approach with simply `memcpy`-ing the input bytes straight into the recipient `long` object(s). It won't be portable in general case, but, again, it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

```
byte b[4];  // Contains bytes
int x= 0;

x= (x << 8) + b[3];
x= (x << 8) + b[2];
x= (x << 8) + b[1];
x= (x << 8) + b[0];
```

I quickly wrote a sample. It's not tested, though.

```
unsigned char b[35];

int sizeOfB = sizeof b / sizeof(unsigned char);

int sizeOfL = sizeOfB / 4;
if(sizeOfB % 4 != 0) ++sizeOfL;
    int lcount=0;

long* l = new long[sizeOfL];

for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfB; i+=4){
    long currentLong = 0;

    if(i + 3 < sizeOfB)
        currentLong = (currentLong << 8) + b[i+3];
    if(i + 2 < sizeOfB)
        currentLong = (currentLong << 8) + b[i+2];
    if(i + 1 < sizeOfB)
        currentLong = (currentLong << 8) + b[i+1];

    currentLong = (currentLong << 8) + b[i+0];

    l[lcount]=currentlong;
    lcount++;
}

// Use l...
delete l;
```

Comment: however I'm surprised that my `gcc -O3` didn't optimize this to a single instruction

Comment: Bad things happen if `byte` is a signed type. I don't know what (if anything) `byte` is on Arduino.

Comment: i think i should add the the byte in my code would refer to a [unsigned char]

Comment: @Dancrumb depending on the system, but on windows x86 and x64 int would be the same as long = 32bit afaik. On Unix x64 a long might be 64 bit = 8byte. really depends on the system

Comment: I can't imagine why you would want to do this anyway if the `byte`s were signed.

Comment: @cppanda what if I have an array of bytes longer than 4 bytes (say 35 bytes in the array) and I want to turn that into an array of longs (where each long is 4 bytes in length)

Comment: @Daniel they are unsigned. They are actually bytecodes that I am converting into a 32 bit string

Comment: @franzras create a long[] with the needed size and then loop through the byte[] and add every 4 byte as a long. in your case if there is an uneven nuber of byte, you need to check if you are over the bounds and if that is the case, only add the remaining 1-3 byte

Comment: @frazras: if they are bytecodes that are being converted to a 32 bit string, then I probably wouldn't go via `long` (which btw is a signed type, but I wouldn't go via `uint32_t` either).

Comment: @SteveJessop I am using the Arduino version of processing. It has signed and unsigned byte, int, long; 8, 16, 32 bytes respectively. Should I opt for unsigned long instead?

Comment: I just meant that if I want to convert 4 bytes to a string, then I wouldn't convert them to *any* integer type. I'd put the string together from the 4 bytes.