# Converting a byte array to an int array in C

Tags: c, arrays, type-conversion, arduino

I have some code below that is supposed to be converting a [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) (Arduino) 8-bit byte array to a 16-bit int array, but it only seems to partially work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The byte array is in little endian byte order. How do I convert it to an int (two bytes per enty) array?

In layman's terms, I want to merge every two bytes.

Currently it is outputting for an input BYTE ARRAY of: `{0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00}`. The output INT ARRAY is: `{1,0,0}`. The output should be an INT ARRAY is: `{1,0,3}`.

The code below is what I currently have:

I wrote this function based on [a solution in Stack Overflow question *Convert bytes in a C array as longs*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295728/convert-bytes-in-a-c-array-as-longs/11295756#11295756).

I also have this solution based off the same code which works fine for byte array to long (32-bits) array `http://pastebin.com/TQzyTU2j`.

```
/**
* Convert the retrieved bytes into a set of 16 bit ints
**/
int * byteA2IntA(byte * byte_slice, int sizeOfB, int * ret_array){

    //Variable that stores the addressed int to be stored in SRAM
    int currentInt;
    int sizeOfI = sizeOfB / 2;

    if(sizeOfB % 2 != 0) ++sizeOfI;
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfB; i+=2){
            currentInt = 0;
            if(byte_slice[i]=='\0') {
                break;
            }
            if(i + 1 < sizeOfB)
                currentInt = (currentInt << 8) + byte_slice[i+1];
            currentInt = (currentInt << 8) + byte_slice[i+0];
            *ret_array = currentInt;
            ret_array++;
        }
        //Pointer to the return array in the parent scope.
        return ret_array;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just cast to int* the pointer to the input array?

Comment: What do you mean with "partially" work? What works, what doesn't?

Comment: @icepack `int` might be 4 bytes and he is converting 2 bytes to an int.

Comment: @alk what about it? the input is just a stream of bytes, not a more complex structure which might've have had alignment issues

Comment: How about short * byteA2IntA(byte * byte_slice) { return (short *)byte_slice;}

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Might work, *if* short is 2 bytes and endianness permits.

Comment: @icepack It was a temp brain laps ... - anyhow byte ordering would lead to portabliity issues.

Comment: @alk aa, I see what you mean. In this case using int is probably not the best choice and 16-bit type would suit better (something like AkiSuihkonen suggested)

Comment: @alk portability issues will be the same any way

Comment: indeed, the code is not yet ready to be delivered ...  @icepack

Comment: @alk Of course it isn't, otherwise he wouldn't ask. ;-)

Comment: One might create the 16bit value in network byte order and then use `ntohs()` to populate the `int` array.

Comment: If `sizeOfB` id odd it is running into UB for the last loop.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295728/convert-bytes-in-a-c-array-as-longs?

Answer (score 2):

What is the meaning of this line of code?

```
if(i + 1 < sizeOfB) currentInt = (currentInt << 8) + byte_slice[i+1];
```

Here `currentInt` is always `0` and `0 << 8 = 0`.

Also what you do is, for each couple of `bytes` (let me call them `uint8_t` from now on), you pack an `int` (let me call it `uint16_t` from now on) by doing the following:

1. You take the rightmost `uint8_t`
2. You shift it 8 positions to the left
3. You add the leftmost `uint8_t`

Is this really what you want?

Supposing you have `byte_slice[] = {1, 2}`, you pack a 16 bit integer with the value 513 (`2<<8 + 1`)!

Also, you don't need to return the pointer to the array of `uint16_t` as the caller has already provided it to the function.

If you use the return of your function, as Joachim said, you get a pointer starting from a position of the `uint16_t` array which is not position `[0]`.

Comment: I wrote this function based on this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295728/convert-bytes-in-a-c-array-as-longs/11295756#11295756

Comment: I also have this solution based off the same code which works fine for byte array to long(32-bits) array http://pastebin.com/TQzyTU2j

Comment: @frazras Maybe you should clarify what you mean by "but it only seems to partially work" :)!

Answer (score 2):

Vincenzo has a point (or two), you need to be clear what you're trying to do;

**Combine two bytes to one 16-bit int, one byte being the MSB and one byte being the LSB**

`int16 result = (byteMSB << 8) | byteLSB;`

**Convert an array of bytes into 16-bit**

```
for(i = 0; i < num_of_bytes; i++)
{
    myint16array[i] = mybytearray[i];
}
```

**Copy an array of data into another one**

```
memcpy(dest, src, num_bytes);
```

That will (probably, platform/compiler dependent) have the same effect as my 1st example.

Also, beware of using ints as that suggests signed values, use uints, safer and probably faster.

Comment: He said it is the first one... But your bitwise or is better than plus for sure

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you increase `ret_array` and then return it. When you return it, it will point to one place beyond the destination array.

Save the pointer at the start of the function, and use that pointer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a struct. This is kind of a hack, though.

Off the top of my head it would look like this.

```
struct customINT16 {
    byte ByteHigh;
    byte ByteLow;
}
```

So in your case you would write:

```
struct customINT16 myINT16;

myINT16.ByteHigh = BYTEARRAY[0];
myINT16.ByteLow = BYTEARRAY[1];
```

You'll have to go through a pointer to cast it, though:

```
intpointer = (int*)(&myINT16);
INTARRAY[0] = *intpointer;
```